# Restrict access to Web Api web services to specific vendors

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Asp.Net Web Api 2.0 based web services which provides functionality such as customer login and access to their information after login. I am using Bearer token authentication for customer login.

Now, lets say I want to restrict access to my web services to only some specific third party vendors who build mobile applications. What are some of the patterns to achieve such restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Its all built in already in the aspnet membership db.. User and roles table are already there.... you just gotta fill them and use authorize tag.. you did not search on google right?

```
   // Restricted by user

    Authorize(Users="smith")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
    }
  //  Restricted by Role
    [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
    }
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/Asp-Net-web-api-authorization-and-authontication/